# JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion

Tags: php, maven

I have Maven 3.3.9 installed as separate .deb on Debian 8.4
I develop php code and have predefined development files tree, that can not leave me follow super strict Maven conventions.
I have two project directories with same structure:

```
.  
├── admin5.php  
.  
├── app  
│   ├── addons  
.   .  
│   └── Tygh  
├── bower_components  
│   └── jquery-sticky  
├── bower.json  
.   .  
├── js  
│   ├── addons  
│   ├── lib  
│   └── tygh  
├── pom.xml  
├── target  
│   ├── classes  
│   ├── dependency-maven-plugin-markers  
│   ├── ip5_bestore-1.0.jar  
│   ├── maven-archiver  
│   └── original-ip5_bestore-1.0.jar  
└── var
```

I have same pom.xml in both:

```
<project  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
          xsi:schemaLocation="  
            http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <groupId>ru.ip-5</groupId>  
  <artifactId>ip5_coolposter</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0</version>  
  <properties>  
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
  </properties>  
  <build>  
    <plugins>  
      <plugin>  
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>2.7</version>  
        <executions>  
          <execution>  
            <id>copy-resources</id>  
            <phase>validate</phase>  
            <goals>  
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>  
            </goals>  
          </execution>  
        </executions>  
        <configuration>  
          <outputDirectory>  {basedir}/src/main/js/addons/ip5_bestore/dependencies/</outputDirectory>  
          <resources>  
            <resource>  
              <directory>  {basedir}/bower_components/fabric.js/dist/</directory>  
              <includes>  
                <include>fabric.min.js</include>  
              </includes>  
            </resource>  
          </resources>  
        </configuration>  
      </plugin>  
      <plugin>  
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>2.4.1</version>  
        <executions>  
          <execution>  
            <phase>package</phase>  
            <goals>  
              <goal>shade</goal>  
            </goals>  
            <configuration>  
              <filters>  
                <filter>  
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>  
                  <excludes>  
                    <exclude>META-INF/</exclude>  
                  </excludes>  
                </filter>  
              </filters>  
            </configuration>  
          </execution>  
        </executions>  
      </plugin>  
    </plugins>  
    <resources>  
      <resource>  
        <directory>  {basedir}</directory>  
        <includes>  
          <include>app/addons/ip5_*/</include>  
          <include>design/backend/css/addons/ip5_*/</include>  
          <include>design/backend/media/images/ip5_*/</include>  
          <include>design/backend/templates/addons/ip5_*/</include>  
          <include>design/themes/responsive/css/addons/ip5_*/</include>  
          <include>design/themes/responsive/media/images/addons/ip5_*/</include>  
          <include>design/themes/responsive/media/fonts/ip5_fonts/</include>  
          <include>design/themes/responsive/styles/data/IP5_*</include>  
          <include>design/themes/responsive/templates/addons/ip5_*/</include>  
          <include>js/addons/ip5_*/</include>  
          <include>var/langs/*/addons/ip5_*.po</include>  
          <include>cmsmagazined1992e543a5d7b4d64afe783fffdbc8d.txt</include>  
        </includes>  
      </resource>  
    </resources>  
  </build>  
</project>
```

When I do "mvn package" at one of them, every thing succeeds, but on the other I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ ip5_bestore ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (default) @ ip5_bestore ---
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /var/www/bestore/target/ip5_bestore-1.0.jar with /var/www/bestore/target/ip5_bestore-1.0-shaded.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it was:
configuration section of copy-resources plugin must be in execution section:

```
<plugin>  
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>2.7</version>  
  <executions>  
    <execution>  
      <id>copy-resources</id>  
      <phase>validate</phase>  
      <goals>  
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>  
      </goals>  
        <configuration>  
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/js/addons/ip5_bestore/dependencies/</outputDirectory>  
          <resources>  
            <resource>  
              <directory>bower_components/jquery-sticky/</directory>  
              <includes>  
                <include>jquery.sticky.js</include>  
              </includes>  
            </resource>  
          </resources>  
        </configuration>  
      </execution>  
    </executions>                         
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

The maven-dependency-plugin `unpack` goal with execution ID "copy" is bound to the `package` phase of the lifecycle.  The maven-resources-plugin `copy-resources` goal with the same execution ID is bound to the `validate` phase.

The `validate` phase occurs before `package`, so the copy is happening before the resources are unpacked. Thus there is nothing to copy, and nothing to package. Change the phase for the "copy" execution to `validate`, and then it should work. Both plugin executions will be bound to the same phase, so the one listed first in the POM runs first. If you'd like to make the order crystal clear regardless of plugin order in the POM, then also change the "copy-resources" execution to run with phase `initialize`.

I'm guessing that it appears to "work" with the first project because the dependencies have already been unpacked somewhere along the way. If you changed the command to `mvn clean package` I suspect both projects would have nothing to package.

You may find the [Maven lifecycle reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) helpful.

Comment: Thank you for VERY clear answer. I tried what you suggested. First of all I get rid of dependency-plugin in this project, now I need just copy-resources. Second, it is true that mvn clean package fails on both. Third, as you suggested I put validate phase (I tried also package and initialize). Bit it still don't work. It works just if I omit the copy-resource-plugin block. Where it can be still problem? Thank you again.

Comment: I found it!!! I put configuration section of copy-resorces block into the execution section!!!